# ERROR: cannot launch node of type [gmapping/slam_gmapping]: can't locate node [slam_gmapping] in package [gmapping]

Tags: navigation, ros-melodic, turtlebot, ros-kinetic, slam-gmapping

[image: Rosanswers logo]

This is my first time using ROS. I'm using ubuntu 18.04 and ROS-melodic on my remote (PC) and ROS-kinetic on my turtlebot (pc). I'm trying to run on my Remote (PC)

```
(roslaunch turtlebot3_slam turtlebot3_slam.launch slam_methods:=gmapping)
```

#### But I get this error!!!!

```
process[robot_state_publisher-1]: started with pid [54409]
ERROR: cannot launch node of type [gmapping/slam_gmapping]: can't locate node [slam_gmapping] in package [gmapping]
process[rviz-3]: started with pid [54410]
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
[robot_state_publisher-1] process has finished cleanly
log file: /home/kaos5-q/.ros/log/2a9e2d58-20d8-11e9-ba50-7085c28192a9/robot_state_publisher-1*.log
libpng warning: iCCP: known incorrect sRGB profile
```

[image: image description]

How can fix this??

### Further Work

- We tried adding the path of `gmapping` to the ROS environment to check if it works

````
```export ROS_PACKAGE_PATH=/home/kaos5-q/catkin_ws/src:/home/kaos5-q/catkin_ws/src/turtlebot3_msgs:/opt/ros/melodic/share:/home/kaos5-q/catkin_ws/src/slam_gmapping/gmapping```
````

- This is what looks like now!
- After I ran, `source ~/.bashrc` Is this what you mean by sourcing??

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/313820/error:-cannot-launch-node-of-type-%5Bgmapping/slam_gmapping%5D:-can%27t-locate-node-%5Bslam_gmapping%5D-in-package-%5Bgmapping%5D/) by [turtlebot3](https://answers.ros.org/users/37964/turtlebot3/) on ROS Answers with karma: 42 on 2019-01-25

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-01-25**:
Do you have the `gmapping` package installed?

**Comment by [turtlebot3](https://answers.ros.org/users/37964/turtlebot3/) on 2019-01-25**:
Yes I have `gmapping` installed! I believe this is a problem with  Ros/environment variables. Setting a ros path for gmapping. That's my assumption. I'm new to ROS, excuse my ignorance.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-01-25**:
How did you install it? From source or using `apt`?

**Comment by [turtlebot3](https://answers.ros.org/users/37964/turtlebot3/) on 2019-01-25**:
I installed it from source.

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-01-25**:
Why did you install from source? You should install the binary using `apt` instead.

**Comment by [turtlebot3](https://answers.ros.org/users/37964/turtlebot3/) on 2019-01-25**:
I tried at first with the binary using `apt` but it didn't work. I searched on google why it didn't work and it's because the package has not been released from the melodic release page. I used this website https://answers.ros.org/question/296170/melodic-gmapping/

**Comment by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) on 2019-01-25**:
OK, that makes sense then. Are you sourcing the workspace in where the package resides and was compiled?

**Comment by [turtlebot3](https://answers.ros.org/users/37964/turtlebot3/) on 2019-01-25**:
I've edited my question a little. I tried to source how you said and it still doesn't work. I'm doing something wrong in here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

You should take a look at [the `catkin` tutorials](https://wiki.ros.org/catkin/Tutorials/create_a_workspace). You need to source your *workspace*.

I'm assuming that you compiled your workspace using

```
catkin_make
```

from the root of your workspace (e.g., `~/catkin_ws`).

Anytime that you open a new terminal, you need to source two files: the `setup.bash` for your ROS distribution and the `setup.bash` for your workspace. It looks like you've already `source`d your distribution's `setup.bash`, now you just need to do the same for your workspace. Again, assuming that the root of your workspace is at `~/catkin_ws` and you are in that directory, then you run

```
source devel/setup.bash
```

and then ROS should be able to find your compiled `gmapping` package and the node(s) that you're using. Now your `ROS_PACKAGE_PATH` environment variable should be set. I've never had to set this on my own.

---

Originally posted by [jayess](https://answers.ros.org/users/26450/jayess/) with karma: 6155 on 2019-01-25

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 1

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [turtlebot3](https://answers.ros.org/users/37964/turtlebot3/) on 2019-01-28**:
Perfect!! It worked

**Comment by [123nusri@gmail.com](https://answers.ros.org/users/57654/123nusri@gmail.com/) on 2020-08-12**:
I already did these things but didn't work.

Answer (score 0):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

For some reason, I got this error because I didn't make the correct installation of ros-melodic-slam-gmapping. After installing the dependency the error went away.

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-melodic-slam-gmapping
```

---

Originally posted by [joaoquintas](https://answers.ros.org/users/3707/joaoquintas/) with karma: 106 on 2020-09-13

This answer was **NOT ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 6

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [osilva](https://answers.ros.org/users/84086/osilva/) on 2021-09-08**:
This works well with noetic as well:

```
$ sudo apt-get install ros-noetic-slam-gmapping
```